# OAuthException: (#100) picture URL is not properly formatted

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

From last few week I have been getting:

```
OAuthException: (#100) picture URL is not properly formatted
```

for some posts. The behaviour is inconsistent.

I am using [Facebook's Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/). I can't think of anything in my code that could warrant this behaviour.

Comment: there is not enough information to go on, add a code snippet of how you are sharing.
If the problem is inconsistent, perhaps some of the image urls are not sent correctly to the API...

Comment: The Problem is the url contains whitespaces. I'm yet trying to figure out how to make it work. urlencode() and rawurlencode() both don't seem to work here.

Answer (score 20):

I faced this problem days ago , and I found that I was sending the image into `"/me/feed"` which must be `"me/photos"`, also I tried posting image from different URLs not included in App Domain URLs. and it works fine for me

Answer (score 2):

Usually #100 error occur when you try to use a URL which is not included in the pre-approved list that you fill out in the basic settings on the app. The list is marked by the "App Domain:" in the image below.

if you are using an external repository you will need to add it for it to work.  You can see below that I have added several to this project.
[image]

Comment: I have successfully used external image files with their URL's domain not present in the app's Facebook settings 'App Domain' section. In my case, this error was due to an underscore present in the domain name of the image URL.