# Facebook PHP publish post with local image

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I trying publish in one of my manage pages, a post with a image, using php sdk, with this code:

```
$filePath = '/testImage.png';
$postParams['source'] = new FacebookFile($filePath);
$postParams['message'] = $post->getMessage();
$response = $this->sendRequest(
'POST',
'/' . $PageId . '/feed',
$postParams,
$pageAccessToken;
);
```

But the result if this,

(#100) picture is not properly formatted

I don't know which parameter I have to use to publish one post with image, after read facebook [page/feed](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.4/page/feed#publish) documentation.

Also I tried, first upload the image and after use object_attachment but does not work.

Also I tried, first upload the image and after use this image link or picture info, but does not work.

Any idea, please?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure you have a proper image, and the path is correct?

Comment: Hi Tobi, yes because I use /PAGE/photos, with this source, and the image has uploaded to page album

Answer (score 1):

finally I found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9125991/oauthexception-100-picture-url-is-not-properly-formatted).

The problem was that it is necessary to change the endpoint from **/PAGEID/feed** to **/PAGEID/photos**, when you want to publish a post with image.

Thanks to Tobi and Kristiyan for your time

Answer (score -1):

In facebook documentation they show that the extension **have to be JPG instead of PNG.**

Read more here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/FacebookFile/5.0.0

Also check again your file path. 
Please use full path.

Comment: This is one example, I tried with JPG and occurs the same, and I use /PAGE/photos, with this source, and the image has uploaded to page album correctly. I need publish a post with one image